# Error itms 90035 - Invalid Signature. Code Object is not signed at all - XCode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, code-signing

I'm writing this message because I really need help. It's been too many hours researching any other similar problems but all solutions that I've tried doesn't solve the problem.

I'm trying to upload our app to the app store and I'm getting the Error `ITMS 90035 - Your Bundle is not signed at all`.

My certificate is valid because I uploaded another app with this certificae just a few hours ago. I've reviewd the ipa file, I've

I'm using Xcode 8 with Swift 3 language and only 1 library added by CocoaPods. I changed the rest of the libraries to include them manually to check if the problem was caused by CocoaPods.

The libraries I have are: GoogleMaps, UberRides, Alamofire, ObjectMapper, OHHTTPStubs. I'm really desperate because I need to upload it on Wednesday, I need to finish more corrections and I cannot correct this problem.

Any help is too much appreciated.

Xcode Window:

[image: Xcode Window]

Error window:

[image: Error window]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using distribution provisioning profile?
Please post a screenshot of your app's settings, `General` tab, `Signing` section(s).
Of course I assume you're using the `Archive`, right?

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Yes, it should be the distribution provisioning profile because I used to upload other app 2 days ago. I have attached the screenshot of the General tab, signing section.[link](http://imgur.com/a/01wMt)

Comment: You have the `Automatically manage signing` checked. One thing to consider would be to uncheck it, and choose a proper Distribution provisioning profile for the `Release` configuration, and then retry to archive the app. I've had some problems with this automatic signing, and in most cases i don't use it. Please remember, that for App Store, you need to have separate provisioning profile for each app id, so the provisioning profile you used 2 days ago for other app is not valid for this app.

Answer (score 0):

Update. Thanks @Łukasz for the information. I finally created a different distribution certificate for this app.

But for those of you which face this problem again I tried the hard way to find what happened. It took me more than a day but I wasted more than half a day deleting and adding files.

The best option is to create a new project, add the icons and then start adding the libraries, one at a time and validate the .ipa file with the option in the Navigator. That's how finally I found one library with and .h and .m file that when added to the project it was placed automatically in the "Copy Bundle Resources" and that should be something that the App Store uploading process doesn't like.

I hope it helps!